# using a function of a plugin in wordpress template or widget

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I use a plugins that show me random quotes in admin pages.
I want to show this quotes in text widget in my template.

I think this is main functions of that plugin

```
function persian_quotes() {
    $chosen = persian_quotes_get_lyric();
    echo "<p id='quotes'>$chosen</p>";
}


add_action('admin_footer', 'persian_quotes');
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to install one of these widgets:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-code-widget/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-text-widget/

And add the function call to the widget once you drop it on the sidebar:

```
persian_quotes();
```